# Why is my light shining though my object when the smoke is on?

Tags: rendering, light

Does anyone know why my lightsource is visible though this object? It ony happens when i apply the smoke! i am using the eevee render. Best regards, Daniel there is a link to my file underneath the pictures
https://www.dropbox.com/s/alm6e5w9gj9ucs0/TextC.blend?dl=0
[image: In this image, the lightsource gets though it fixture, this is visible and caused by the smoke. the rest of the source is good visible]
[image: Here there is no smoke, so no beam visible]

Comment: @stphnl329 I know! Thats why i want the smoke, but in real  life i dont see the lamp inside the fixture through the fixture, so why is that happening in blender?

Answer (score 0):

> Smoke is made up small particles, gases and water vapor. Water vapor
>   makes up the majority of smoke.

When light passes through smoke, it reflects off these particles into the camera. That's why you can shine a light/laser beam through mist/smoke in real life and get the same effect.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU6JNGxfxnY

**Edit:**

According to the Blender manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/lighting.html#shadows):

> **Clip Start**:
>   Distance from the light object at which the shadow map starts. Any object before this distance will not appear to cast shadows. Clip Start will only appear for point, spot and area lights.
>
> **Contact Shadows** This type of shadow exists to fix light leaking caused
>   by bias or shadow map undersampling. It uses the depth buffer to find
>   occluders (just like Screen Space Reflections). However, just like
>   Screen Space Reflections it has the same limitations, namely, unknown
>   object thickness and effect disappearing at screen edges.

Unfortunately, no matter how much I played with the light settings, I couldn't get rid of the lighting issues. I thought that maybe it was the holes in the mesh that was causing the issue, but replacing the light housings with inset cylinders didn't work either.

I found a solution, but its just a makeshift coverup for the issue. The result is shown below:

[image]

And here's the secret behind the scenes madness:

[image]

Comment: I also thought it's just a dispersion, but look at the light position. Shouldn't it be invisible inside the lamp?

Comment: Maybe it's just the rendered viewport mode, there are discrepancies between rendered view port and renders. Haven't tried it yet though

Comment: Hi! Yes, the light should be invisible inside the lamp, and this is rendered in viewport, but when i render the animation, i get the same effect.

Comment: @stphnl329 I know! Thats why i want the smoke, but in real life i dont see the lamp inside the fixture through the fixture, so why is that happening in blender?

Comment: @DaniëlVegter could you upload your blend file? It would help if I could see all the settings

Comment: @stphnl329 of course!

Comment: @DaniëlVegter Alright...did the best I could.

Comment: @stphnl329 Thanks!